# Weird behavior of spinner in TablelLayout with list view

Tags: android, listview, spinner, tablelayout

I am trying to put table layout in list view in that table layout i have one spinner which is not displaying properly it is stretched in width and doesn't looks good. I am inflating the table layout in the getView() method of CustomAdapter which extends BaseAdapter

```
@Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            final int pos = position;
            final ViewHolder fHolder;
            ViewHolder holder ;
            View view = null;

            if(convertView == null) { // InflateViewHelper class is returning
                                     // object of View class In InflateViewHelper class
                                    //i have written
                                //View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.table_layout, null); 

                InflateViewHelper inflateView = new InflateViewHelper(inflater, aShoppingItem.get(position), mContext);
                view = inflateView.createView();


                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.txtUnitPrice = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtUnitPrice);
                holder.txtTotalPrice = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtTotalPrice);
                holder.spinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner);

                view.setTag(holder);

            }
            else {

                view = convertView;
                holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();

            }
fHolder = holder;
            holder.spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(
                    new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int iposition, long id)
                        {

                            value = parent.getItemAtPosition(iposition).toString();

                            if( pos<totalItems.size())
                                totalItems.set(pos, value);
                            else
                                totalItems.add(pos,value);



                            int number = Integer.parseInt(value);
                            int unit = Integer.parseInt(fHolder.txtUnitPrice.getText().toString());
                            String total =  String.format("%d", unit*number);
                            fHolder.txtTotalPrice.setText(total);
                            String amnt = fHolder.txtTotalPrice.getText().toString();
                            Log.v("AMOUNT", amnt);

                            if( pos< totalAmount.size())
                                totalAmount.set(pos, amnt);
                            else
                                totalAmount.add(pos, amnt);

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                            totalItems.add(pos, value);
                            Log.v("VALUE@@@@", value);          
                        }

            });

            int number = Integer.parseInt(value);
            int unit =         Integer.parseInt(holder.txtUnitPrice.getText().toString());
            String total =  String.format("%d", unit*number);
            holder.txtTotalPrice.setText(total);

            return view;
        }
```

if i try this code in simple table layout it works properly
can any tell me where i am going wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long time a got the solution for this problem.
To get ride of this problem i have used a 9 patch image and put it as a background of spinner and i get slimmer spinner. I got this answer from [this link](http://kmansoft.com/2010/04/19/compact-spinner-widgets/)